# Does "git status" scan the content of all files?

Tags: git

I just started working with Git, and I'm wondering exactly what "git status" is checking. Does it actually hash each tracked file each time it's run, or does it use some hint indicators like modified timestamp and size to judge which files it should scan for modifications?

Comment: If you can read [the source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/wt-status.c) (I can't =)) - the answer is in there.

Comment: As an additional question, since the above seems to have partially answered my question - how can I _force_ git to do a full scan of the content of all the files?

Comment: Sounds like a separate question to me! :-)